# Selenium sendkeys stop working for browse dialog box

Tags: python, selenium

I had this bit of code that works for years but all of a sudden stopped. The element is found and keys are sent (no error) but no text shows in browse dialog box. Interfacing with popular photo sharing website. Selecting a picture for the post. I've tried clear and clicking suggestions from other posts but it errors. I also tried changing my file from a .jpg to jpeg like mentioned in other posts.

```
image_filename = 'C:\\filefolder\\subfolder\\image.jpeg'
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input').send_keys(image_filename) 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys(image_filename)

<div class="_a3gq"> <div class="_a3gq"> <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" role="presentation"> <input accept="image/jpeg" class="_ac69" type="file"> </form></div><section class="_a997 _a998"><div></div>
```

Comment: Add the `HTML` source for the element and the error that you are getting?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I'm not sure how to get the HTML source because the file select window blocks chrome and I can't bring it to the front. I'm not getting an error, it's completing but no filename is being typed into the file select like it was before.

Comment: I would refine that locator... by tag name of "input" is not very well defined.  Right-click on the input box you are trying to type in and choose, "Inspect".   If you are talking about a browse dialog, that is not accessible to Selenium.  Usually you'd just send the path to the file to the input tag of type="file".  That'll set it's value attribute to the file path just as if you had browsed for the file.  You can then submit the form to upload.  (use .submit() method for convenience)

Comment: @pcalkins I'm not sure how to use submit, but I've changed the code to `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys(image_filename)` and still have the same issue

Comment: try: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").submit()  If that doesn't help you might need to trigger on onchange event.

Comment: I tried submit and this was the error "{AttributeError}'NoneType' object has no attribute 'submit'" I'll look into onchange. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used pywinauto to get this working. Thank you for all the comments. They made me realize I couldn't do it with Selenium

```
image_filename = 'myimagename.jpg'
app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(title_re='Open')
window = app.Dialog
window.SetFocus()
window.TypeKeys(image_filename)
logger.info('image selected')
app.Dialog.Open.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

selenium is for web automation, but the browser dialog box is windows dialog, need use desktop automation technology, such as pywinauto, autoit, or clicknium(support both desktop and web automation)